# Running Jersey samples

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

I just downloaded the Jersey samples which is a maven project but when I 
try to execute the samples I get

> "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:checkstyle
>   (default-cli) on project json-jackson: An error has occurred in
>   Checkstyle report generation. Failed during checkstyle execution:
>   Unable to find suppressions file at location:
>   etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml: Could not find resource
>   'etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml'. -> [Help 1]"

I think it might be related to the parent pom, however I did not find a solution yet.

Any idea how can this be resolved ?

Comment: You should create an different project and just copy the content (adjusting the pom as needed)

Comment: will try but these type of samples normally are delivered to be executed without any changes

Comment: I don't know, may you're right. I don't think I ever tried. I always just create a new project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I open a bug on jira https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3011

Solution provided :

simple workaround: clone whole Jersey repo and build just examples (you'll have etc/* dir downloaded).
Or you can try to disable checkstyle:
mvn clean install -PcheckstyleSkip

Comment: Use cmd, go to directory where has file pom.xml, then run command: `mvn jetty:run -PcheckstyleSkip` browse address: `http://localhost:8080` will success.

Comment: 3+ years later...the current instructions say to run via `mvn clean compile exec:java`. Combining this with the answer above yields: `mvn clean compile exec:java -PcheckstyleSkip`, which works beautifully. Thank you, @Cris!